# Visual Studio Team Services undo a checkout file

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any easy way to undo a checkout file on located on Visual Studio Team Services?? I have a project here https://mydomain.visualstudio.com and need to know how can you forcefully undo any checkout.

Comment: Do you want to undo a checkin or checkout?

Comment: i want undo a checkout file of another user

Comment: If you are an admin for VC you can use the follow command line tf undo /workspace:OtherUserWorkspace;OtherUser  $/Project/ItemName.cs /s:http://mydomain.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
You can use the tf workspace command to list the other users worksapces

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TF.exe utility and [undo command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4.aspx) from the Visual Studio Command Prompt to undo a users changes

```
c:\>tf undo /collection:http://fabrikam-3:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
/workspace:FABRIKAM-1;JuliaI $/SiteApp/Main/SolutionA/Project1/program.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47b0c7w9.aspx) command to unlock a file that been checkout by other user or use [tf undo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c72skhw4.aspx) command to remove the pending changes.

Refer to this article from MSDN for details: [How to: Remove Another User's Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470670(v=vs.90).aspx)